# How to use basic indexing with multiple conditionals

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

As you know, basic indexing in Pandas is really easy.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4]})
```

Let's say I want every row where 'a' is greater than 2.

```
df[df['a'] > 2]
```

Ok, but now how do I use multiple conditionals? Let's try and find every row where 'a' is in range(2,4).

```
df[df['a'] in range(2,4)]
df[1 < df['a'] < 4]
df[df['a'] >1 and df['a'] <4]
```

All of these lines return the error message:

"The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

But as far as I can tell, these methods don't do what I'm attempting.

EDIT:
Found the answer right after posting.

```
df[df.a > 1][df.a < 4]
```

Comment: It's great that you found a solution. However note that the solutions from @Grayrigel are more efficient, especially the one using between().

Answer (score 1):

You can separate multiple conditions in the parenthesis separating them `&` (and) or `|` (or). Here is an example:

```
df[(df.a > 1) & (df.a < 4)]
```

Alternatively, in this case, you can also use `gt`(greater than) or `lt` (less than) like this:

```
df[df.a.gt(1) & df.a.lt(4)]
```

Or you can use the `between` method:

```
df[df.a.between(1,4, inclusive=False)]
```

**Output**:

```
   a
1  2
2  3
```

Comment: Added an answer. Let me know if it works for you.